# Proposition 2.14 iii) Atiyah Macdonald introduction to commutative algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra

Hi I am refering to proposition 2.14 in Atiyah-MacDonald introduction to commutative algebra and I can't find the bilinear maps that will induce $A$-module homomorphisms $f,g$ where 
$f:(M \oplus N) \otimes P \to (M \otimes P) \oplus (N \otimes P)$ , 
$ g :(M \otimes P) \oplus (N \otimes P) \to (M \oplus N) \otimes P $

and $f \circ g = id$ and $g \circ f = id $, hence $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map $f$ is induced from $$(M \oplus N) \times P \rightarrow (M \otimes P) \oplus (N \otimes P),$$ $$((m,n),p) \mapsto ((m,p),(n,p))$$ while $g$ is obtained by first inducing maps $$g_1 : M \otimes P \rightarrow (M \oplus N) \otimes P,$$ $$g_2 : N \otimes P \rightarrow (M \oplus N) \otimes P$$ from the bilinear maps $$M \times P \rightarrow (M \oplus N) \otimes P,$$ $$(m,p) \mapsto ((m,0),p)$$ and $$N \times P \rightarrow (M \oplus N) \otimes P,$$ $$(n,p) \mapsto ((0,n),p).$$  Then using the universal property of direct sum induces the desired map $g$.